# react-scroll-parallax <ParallaxProvider/> to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, parallax

I am trying to make react-scroll-parallax work on a div using this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax

I am trying to set up the parallax provider to not just point to the body but to a specific div. I am trying to ref the element (which is the scrollContainer).

The challenge is that I am using a "scrolling div" between the footer and the header, so doing the parallax on the  would not work.

I tried to create a ref and reference it on the  without success.

The documentation says to ref an element as an option to ScrollContainer:
scrollContainer Element:    Optionally set the container that has overflow and will contain parallax elements. Defaults to the HTML body

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myScrollDiv = React.createRef();
  }

/////////////////



<ParallaxProvider scrollContainer={this.myScrollDiv.current}>
     <div className="page-scroller site-wrapper pb-5" ref={this.myScrollDiv}>
               ///Content
     </div>
</ParallaxProvider>

I would love for the .page-scroller div to handle parallax.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I've never used *react-scroll-parallax* library. The answer is base-off on the source code.

Welcome to Stack Overflow, @stephanesng

As I looked into the source code, I found a Storybook [code snippet](https://github.com/jscottsmith/react-scroll-parallax/blob/cb67ad7a40368ea03a660963f2beb77323b8e30c/stories/ScrollContainer.js#L25).

It looks like you need to pass the `ref` variable itself, not `ref.current`.

```
export default class ScrollContainer extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        scrollAxis: 'vertical',
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            scrollContainer: null,
        };
        this.scrollContainer = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ scrollContainer: this.scrollContainer.current });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // ............ You pass the `ref` not `ref.current`                        
            <div className="scroll-container" ref={this.scrollContainer}>
                <ParallaxProvider
                    scrollContainer={this.state.scrollContainer}
                    scrollAxis={this.props.scrollAxis}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </ParallaxProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So that means, you'd need to pass `this.myScrollDiv`, not `this.myScrollDiv.current` to `scrollContainer` prop.

And also, your `ref` needs to be outside of the `ParallaxProvider`.

```
<div className="page-scroller site-wrapper pb-5" ref={this.myScrollDiv}>
    <ParallaxProvider scrollContainer={this.myScrollDiv}>
               ///Content
    </ParallaxProvider>
</div>
```

If I am wrong, I will delete the answer.